# IE won't split string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, split

I have the following code:

```
$('#smallcart .plusone').live('click',function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   articlenr = id.split('_')[1];
});
```

this works fine in FF, safari, Chrome, however in IE (7 and 8) it throws an error on the split-function (this property or method is not supported by this object).

if I alert the 'id'-variable I get something like `plus_5751`. (so I want to get the '5751' part)
if I do `alert(typeof(id))` I get `String` as an answer...

Maybe somebody can point me to the right answer?

Thx

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453521/javascript-split-doesnt-work-in-ie

Comment: @Paniyar: that's not a duplicate.  The issue in that question is due to the use of regular expressions to split a string - this question is about splitting a string by another string.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it: http://jsbin.com/imoki3

Comment: works fine for me ( [example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/QvNPg/1/) ). How about adding the script tag, and better yet a link to a working page..

Comment: @Kobi - really? I knew it! IE is getting personal with me! Still throwing an error when I try it... :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `split` works pretty well in IE. The problem is the part left of the equal-sign. It's an object with all input-fields having the name `articlenr` and therefor IE quits with 'this property or method is not supported by this object' when you're trying to assign a string to it.

Comment: Yes!!! It works if I put 'var' in front of 'articlenr'. Thank you so much, I hope you and everybody you love, has a wonderful day!

Comment: @Ian - if this answered your question, consider clicking the tick to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works just fine for me in Internet Explorer - as it should be expected to.  The problem must lie elsewhere, perhaps something is overriding *String.prototype.split*?.  You can see a working example of your code at http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/6K77Y/.  The first thing to check for is any Internet Explorer specific code in your scripts.

I would make one small improvement for efficiency.  `$(this).attr('id');` is pretty much the long winded way of writing `this.id`.  It's slower, because a new jQuery object has to be created and then the *attr* function has to run.  Without it, your code can be compressed more, whilst still remaining very readable, if you like:

```
$('#smallcart .plusone').live('click',function(){
   articlenr = this.id.split('_')[1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try renaming your variable 'id' to something else.  IE doesn't like it when you name things in your scripts the same as items in the DOM.</strike>

Never mind, that seems to have not been the issue in this case.  I have, however, had issues in the past with IE specific bugs caused by variable names.

Comment: That's not the problem, `id` is declared as a local variable with the `var` keyword here.

Comment: there is not item in the dom with an `ID` of `id`

Comment: That's a good tip: there are names that do fail (`status`, for one), but `var` should help here and `id` seems ok.