# Would the javascript .split(' ') leave the commas in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a space separated string that I want to make into an array. I am using the `.split(' ')` method to do this. Will the resulting array have those spaces in it? For example if my string is `"joe walked down the street"` and I performed the method on it would the array look like this `["joe", "walked", "down", "the", "street"]` or will it look like this `["joe ", "walked ", "down ", "the ", "street "]`?

Comment: In light of your username... you can test out javascript interactively when using Chrome's built in javascript console (View > Developer > JavaScript Console on mac, Page > Developer > Debug Javascript pc, i think).  For questions like this one, it might be faster to just pull up your console and find out.  It's also a handy tool when answering questions on StackOverflow ;o

Comment: @Daniel Mendel ok, thanks. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, it would *not* have the spaces in there.  It would look like this:

```
["joe", "walked", "down", "the", "street"]
```

Since spaces are a bit hard to see, let's take a more visible example with the same effect:

```
var str = "joe...walked...down...the...street";
var arr = str.split("...");
alert(arr); //["joe", "walked", "down", "the", "street"]
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/YQD9p/).

Answer (score 2):

Note that for more complicated uses of split (eg splitting on a regexp), IE's split does NOT work correctly. There is a cross-browser implementation of split that works correctly.

See [JavaScript: split doesn't work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453521/javascript-split-doesnt-work-in-ie)

Answer (score 1):

It will remove the spaces.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp