# \n is not working in IE text area

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, split, textarea

I am using this jquery to add some elements of the page and add them to a text area

```
$('#chk_editor').append($('#greeting').text()).append('\n \nI want it to be known that').show();
```

Internet Explorer ignores the /n, I found this question that addresses the issue with split()
[Javascript split() not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511741/javascript-split-not-working-in-ie)

I'm not sure how to implement it into my code, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `\r\n`.

This is the Windows style line ending. `\n` is the UNIX style line ending.

Comment: I understand this is the most succinct answer, the answer I ticked allowed me to work more flexibly with the code which was a little bonus.

Comment: Sorry until I opened windows xp, worked well in windows 7, your answer works in both..

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
    var text = $("#chk_editor").val();
    text = text + $("#greeting").html();
    text = text + "\n \n I want to be known.";
    $("#chk_editor").val(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

try one of those 2 options:

1) for any string that contain **\n** you can do somthing like:

```
  function adjustText(messageString)
 {
   return messageString.replace('\n', '\r\n');
 }
 ....
 $('#chk_editor').append($('#greeting').text()).append(adjustText(message));
```

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5899275/1219182

2) try to use the jquery-`val()` property (when setting textArea) instead of text()

```
$('#chk_editor').val("some text....\n ...bla bla \n...)
```

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/5583094/1219182