# Why does my string.split() call fail in internet explorer?

Tags: javascript

This works perfectly in chrome and firefox, and it SHOULD work perfectly in internet explorer.

In fact, if I manually enter a string instead of taking it from the prompt, it works perfectly.  The only issue is when I take in the string using 'prompt', and as far as I can tell the value I'm getting from that is a string, just like any other!

```
    value=prompt("extract","youtube code here");
    el=document.getElementById('textarea');
    //matches=value.match(/.*<embed src=(^>*)>.*/gi);
    item=value.split('<embed src=')[1];
    closeTag=item.indexOf('>');
    if(closeTag>-1)
    {
        item=item.substring(0,closeTag);
    }
    alert(item);
    el.value+=item;
```

Comment: Read the source after load, do you see "embed" getting passed, or "object"?

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453521/javascript-split-doesnt-work-in-ie?

Comment: I recommend `var startTag = value.indexOf('<embed src=');var closeTag = startTag<0?-1:value.indexOf('>', startTag);` This code will never fail (your code will fail when the split argument is not given, ie `<embed src=` is missing).

Comment: Also, throw an alert/console.log in there to see what value is before you split it...

Comment: I went into the IE debugger and used some alerts; alert (typeof value) shows that value is supposed to be a string, the debugger doesn't name it a string but it sure looks like it is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your variables and it seems to work for me in IE7:

```
var value=prompt("extract","youtube code here");
var el=document.getElementById('textarea');
//matches=value.match(/.*<embed src=(^>*)>.*/gi);
var item=value.split('<embed src=')[1];
var closeTag=item.indexOf('>');
if(closeTag>-1)
{
    item=item.substring(0,closeTag);
}
alert(item);
el.value+=item;
```

Comment: OK, that was an incredibly easy fix...  and researching it caused me to discover a critical flaw in my understanding of javascript.  I thought adding var made a global variable, turns out it's the opposite... woops!