# IE8 parses this simple regex differently from all other browsers

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to use this function to create **2** results from `value`

```
function split(val){
  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
};
value = "Jim, ";
var terms = split( value );

terms;
```

All other browsers including IE9, will produce `terms = ["Jim", ""]`

However, IE8 and probably IE7 produces this : `terms = ["Jim"]`

Does anyone have any suggestions or alternatives that could possibly work for IE8 ?

Comment: Interesting find. IE8 behaves properly when splitting with a string (such as `", "` in this example), but doesn't have that empty string at the end when splitting on a regex... strange.

Comment: For an alternative, see the answer on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453521/javascript-split-doesnt-work-in-ie][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453521/javascript-split-doesnt-work-in-ie

Comment: Can you explain in which case you'll worry about empty last element on array? 
Take a look at my edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be better off going with:

```
val.split(',')
```

This seems to work consistently in all browsers.

Any trailing whitespace after the commas still has to be stripped off afterwards. Something along the lines of:

```
for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
    terms[i] = terms[i].replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
}
```

Apparently, in IE8 and earlier, empty-string matches are ignored by `split()` when a regex parameter is used. A string parameter works fine:

```
'axx'.split('x')    // All browsers: ["a", "", ""]
'axx'.split(/x/)    // IE6/7/8: ["a"], all other browsers: ["a", "", ""]
```

Answer (score -1):

You're going to have to rewrite the regex.

Try this.

```
String.prototype.trim = String.prototype.trim || function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
}
function split( str ){
    return (""+str).trim().split( /\,/ );
}
```