# Is this expected behaviour for .split() in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I just came across an issue in IE8, using the `.split()` method.

```
element.name = 'question[10]';
var splitName = element.name.split(/\[([0-9]+)\]/);
// Split name just had 1 element, 
//    splitName[0] == 'question'
// In Chrome/Firefox it has 3
//    splitName[0] == 'question'
//    splitName[1] == '10'
//    splitName[2] == ''
```

I've found a work around using [this code](https://gist.github.com/bbogovich/2611473), but I'm curious if this is a bug with IE8, or if this is expected, and there is a better way to achieve the same result without needing to modify the split method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: split doesn't work in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453521/javascript-split-doesnt-work-in-ie)

Comment: If the names are in the format `question[n]` I would not use an RE at all ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected (somewhat) behaviour.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses,
>   then each time separator is matched, the results (including any undefined
>   results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array.
>   However, not all browsers support this capability.)

Delete the parentheses from the regular expression and the results will almost be the same ( Chrome/FF take the notion of a 'separator' at the end of a string verbatim in producing another empty string ).